# How To Remove Login Preference value after specific time?

Tags: android, android-activity

i have a scenario, user logins and goes to activity A in my android application, now i have a requirement to validate user after every three hours

if application is running and 3 hours passed then take him to login screen, if not then just remove session value from prefrence file

which technique should i used for this? service? or what ?

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A service could be used to do this. Where you have an alarm that you set 3 hours in advance and keep checking the Session and ensure that the session is valid.

Answer (score -1):

i think it is usefull to you

```
     if ((backupThread != null) && (backupThread.isAlive())) {
        if (debug) Log.d(TAG,"wait for backup thread");
        int maxWaitToDie=500000;
        try { backupThread.join(maxWaitToDie); } 
        catch(InterruptedException e){} //  ignore
```

Comment: thank for your reply.any reference to backupThread ? please explain it in bit detail its not clear to me.